# NSXML Parser Cannot Find Element Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse XML from a .NET WCF Webservice using NSXML Parser. 
Here is the XML which my web-service returns:

```
<QuestionnaireXML xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/QuestionnaireDescriptor" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QuestionnaireName>Clinic Waiting Room Feedback</QuestionnaireName>
    <Questions>
        <Question>
            <Answers>
                <Answer>
                     <AnswerTitle>Windows</AnswerTitle>
                </Answer>
                <Answer>
                    <AnswerTitle>Mac</AnswerTitle>
                </Answer>
            </Answers>
            <QuestionID>363</QuestionID>
            <QuestionName>Windows or Mac?</QuestionName>
        </Question>
    </Questions>
</QuestionnaireXML>
```

I obtain the XML using the following method:

```
-(IBAction)getQuestionnaire
{
    // Obtain questionnaire ID from input textfield
    NSString *qid = questionnaireId.text;

    // Begin creating URL string and contact web service
    dataWebService = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *combinedRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.osqar.co.uk/OsqarWCF/frank.svc/getQuestionnaireForID?id=%@", qid];
    NSURL * myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:combinedRequest];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: myURL];
    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [myConnection start];  
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    [dataWebService setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    [dataWebService appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    XMLParser *parseQuestionnaire = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    Questionnaire *myQuestionnaire = [parseQuestionnaire parseXML:responseString];  
}
```

And then parse the XML to the XMLParser class and it method. Like So:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Questionnaire.h"

@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize xmlParser;

-(Questionnaire *)parseXML:(NSString *)xml
{    
    userRet = [[Questionnaire alloc] init];
    NSData *data = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    self.xmlParser.delegate = self;
    if([self.xmlParser parse])
    {
        NSLog(@"The Xml is parsed.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to parse the XML");
    }

    return userRet;
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser parseErrorOccurred: (NSError *) parseError 
{
    NSLog(@"Error Parser:%@",[parseError localizedDescription]);
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName
   namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI
  qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName
     attributes: (NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"QuestionnaireName"]) 
    {
        NSString *name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"QuestionnaireName"];
        NSLog(@"QuestionnaireName: %@", name);
        userRet.QuestionnaireName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"QuestionnaireName"];
    }   
}
```

My problem here is that the element name **QuestionnaireName** is apparently not being found. I have placed a break point and the code steps into **didStartElement** method but then steps out of the **if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"QuestionnaireName"])** statement.

As you can see from the XML sample above, the Element QuestionnaireName clearly exists.
What am I doing wrong here? Have I missed out anything?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated but in didStartElement, if the element is "QuestionnaireName", you are then looking for an attribute of the same name.  According to your sample xml, the element QuestionnaireName has no attributes (eg. QuestionnaireXML has two attributes: xmlns and xmlns:i).  Have you implemented the other delegate methods like foundCharacters and didEndElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to set `currentelement = elementName` in the method **didstartelement**.

Now have to implement the method **foundcharacter**.

In that method check the following:

```
if ([currentelement isEqualtoString:@"QuestionnaireName"])
{    
    NSLog(@"value  %@",string);    
}
```

then you will get value "Clinic Waiting Room Feedback"

Comment: Declare NSString *currentelement in .h file